# Screen dims while playing game

Tags: ios, iphone

In my iPhone app, when people are playing it, the screen goes black until you touch it again  after they play it for a couple minutes. Is there any way for me to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I see that line of code in that question, but it doesn't specify where to put it exactly which is my confusion

Comment: @user3456713 put it in applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions or in viewDidLoad